# Does the interval $[-c,\infty)$, with $c>0$, contain $-\infty$?

Tags: notation, infinity

I think my question boils down to some kind of definition, which I am not aware of.

> Does the interval $[-c,\infty)$, with $c>0$, contain $-\infty$?

On the one hand, $c\to +\infty$ is possible; but, on the other hand, I fixed $c$ as $c$.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Infinity is not a real number

Comment: When talking about intervals of *real numbers* the only elements in the interval are themselves *real numbers*.  Neither $\infty$ nor $-\infty$ are real numbers and so are not included in any interval of real numbers.

Comment: Compare this to when talking about intervals of *extended real numbers* where $\infty$ and $-\infty$ are actually valid values.  Even then however, $[c,\infty)$ does not include $\infty$ and does not include $-\infty$ unless $c$ happens to *be* $-\infty$.  The parenthesis on an end of an interval notation implies that the value at that end is not included.  $[c,\infty]$ on the other hand *will* include $\infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition you're missing is that of a 'real number'. Infinity is not a real number, but merely an expression to denote that a sequence does not converge.

If you let $c$ go to infinity, you eventually include any of the numbers not in your original interval, so the resulting interval will contain all the (existing) real numbers, but not the (non-existent) "number" $-\infty$.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your interval is in the real numbers, "infinity" is not contained in any interval. Intervals on the real line consist of elements which are real numbers. $\infty$ is not a real number.